# data access layer - modularity and reusability

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I am really new at this and I am trying to find the best data access layer architecture for me.
I have 3 layers in my solution:

1. Presentation layer - ASP.net application
2. Business logic layer - c# objects and logic
3. Data access layer - functions that call stored procedures.

I want replace the data access layer.

In case I use the Entity Framework or NHibernate, for example, what will ensure that later I would be able to replace that data access layer without making changes in the business logic layer?
Where comes the use of interfaces in the Entity Framework, or NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to preserve the business layer you must keep the model as well. Because the business has a very tight connection to the model.

What you can change is the layer that maps your model to the database.

Both `NHibernate` and `Entity Framework` 4.1 allow what we call POCO objects. POCO objetcs are pure CLR objects that do not reference any persistence-specific classes. That is: It does not contain any attributes or base classes, or method calls that would couple this class to an assembly. While using NHibernate you can map these POCO classes to the database by using XML files or a fluent methodology using Fluent NHibernate. In EF4.1 you can only use the fluent methodology.

One thing you have to concern about is the use of `stored procedures`. That is something that by nature compromises persistence layer substitution. EF4.1 POCO approach currently does not support stored procedures. NHibernate probably does but I'm not sure.

**EDIT**

As Matthew Cox mentioned. Of course there will be need for interfaces when it comes to the DAL classes. Because CRUD operations will vary among persistence layers. These interfaces will allow for persistence substitution.

Example:

```
public class IPersonDAL {
    IList<Person> GetPeople();
    void InsertPerson(Person person);
    ...
}
```

Comment: So what you say is that in the data access layer I actually need the model objects, interfaces and the ef/nhibernate classes?

Comment: @Naor: To be clearer: On your model layer, you will have entities that represent your database. On your business layer you will have your business logic. On this layer you will reference the model layer and manipulate it through interfaces that represent your DAL. Everything I mention so far won't need to be replaced if you replace your database. Another layer that is needed is a layer that will implement these interfaces AND map the POCO classes from the model to the database. This layer may needed to be replaced in the future

Comment: Thanks for the usefull info! Last thing to be sure, In the business logic layer I have also objects that represent the data from the db, but those objects are used in the logics and they are not POCO. So the proccess will be: first loading the data from the db using the DAL, then convert the data to POCO objects of the model layer and last convert the poco object into business objects. Is this the right sequence?

Answer (score 2):

Design an interface that maps out all key methods that you would use at your DAL. Then only reference the DAL classes by the interface. This will give it modularity by decoupling the layers from each other.

Whenever you need to swap the said DAL out, you just need to insert a new DAL that implements the said interface. The rest of your code will be none the wiser for the change.

Just one approach to your problem.

Comment: Is there any relation to POCO? Does POCO solves this problem?

Comment: @Naor: Matthew is refering to the DAL layer. At the DAL layer you will indeed need interfaces. What has relation to POCO is the model object you pass and receive from the DAL layer.

Comment: +1 The DAL layer will need to implement the interfaces, but they should be defined externally (often together with the consumer).

Answer (score 1):

Specifically nHibernate (3.0+) and EF support LINQ, as such you code create a simple IRepository interface which accepts an `Expression<Func<TItemType,bool>>` and avoid having repositories that have GetPersonByID, getPersonByName etc. While this might hinder you in swapping an ORM I think that you won't use an ORM that doesn't support LINQ.

This interface might look something like this (this is **NOT** a complete implementation! this is **just** a demonstration, and the real interface will need better refinment! This is just something I've mocked up now! This might need to also need implement IDisposable, etc.):

```
interface IRepository<TPersistant>
{
      void Save(TPersistant item);
      void Delete(TPersistant item);

      TPersistant Find(Expression<Func<TPersistant,bool>> predicate); 
      // maybe findOne or findMany

      // maybe something like this
      IQueryable<TPersistant> Query();
      /* Other stuff like updating, transactions, commiting, etc.*/
}
```

I would, however, like to mention some things that people ignore when abstracting the DAL. **This o/c is all my opinion**.

While abstracting can help you "swap" the DAL in the future, I would think hard if you gain anything by it, except creating software that goes by "best practices" and what "people say you should do", and on the other hand shooting yourself in the foot.

When you abstract the DAL completely you might lose other ORM specific features which actually make one ORM better than the other, or even future performance optimizations for the sake of abstractions. i/e Future queries in nHibernate (which imo are a huge feature), which you basically lose if you abstract it away. You might also lose lazy initialization optimizations (Select N+1 problems) as you can't use Fetch (nHibernate) or Include (EF). Even small things like enum support (which I believe EF STILL doesn't support).

I would also like to add that a lot of developers create abstractions for the sake of future changes, while in reality these changes almost never happen.

So while I'm **not** saying don't abstract the DAL, because there are **a lot** of advantages like unit testing, decoupling etc. (although you can always create a coupled-to-dal repository which would help with unit testing), it's something that should be **heavily considered** if it's worth paying the paying the price of some features that actually make nhibernate/EF better than the other.